# Having sub-sites hurts SO

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange

Why does Stack Exchange keep adding programming sites...

- http://codereview.stackexchange.com
- http://programmers.stackexchange.com
- http://codegolf.stackexchange.com

I feel like this hurts Stack Overflow more than it helps. They should be all in one site! Stack Overflow works because it has a giant community, breaking up the community into smaller groups will hurt the quest for getting a good answers.

I am sure there are people on this site that can answer a codereview question, and vice-versa... then why are the sites split? People can answer the question on both sites, which means they have the same user base. Why would you try to split the community? They should all be one site because we have a common interest in helping people with code/programming. Why can't there be a `codereview` tag, instead of an entire new site, which splits the community.

Comment: I don't think I've heard 2 referred to as "so many" before... and as for "keep adding" - those sites have been around for really quite a long time. When do you think the last was added?

Comment: Don't forget "Code Golf" and "Software Recommendations [for programmers]"

Comment: And Computer Science, to some extent.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: That's a reasonable point, but in that case the OP should have included them - there's no point in providing a list if it's just "a couple that I happened to think of". Personally I'm glad they're separate sites, mind you...

Comment: Can you demonstrate how these sites are hurting Stack Overflow? Most sites that spin off have a much higher answered percentage than SO, so they're not hurting the quest to get good answers.

Comment: @JonSkeet Your right, the list isn't extensive... removed "so many"

Comment: @JonSkeet I am too.  I was remembering back to the "You should just ignore the tags you dont' like" argument that preceded Stack Exchange; and remembering how much those days sucked. I'm glad it is like it is.

Comment: @BilltheLizard It just seemed to me that it hurt the community... I just don't want to have two separate reputation points lol. Glad you shared that, I guess I was more curious to hear what the arguments are for having sub-sites.

Comment: @Arian *Why* does it seem to you to hurt the community.  Don't tell us *that* it hurts, explain in what way, *specifically*, it is harmful.

Comment: **[area51.se] is the culprit**, we should stop new sites from popping up right there in the origin :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Those sites were created because the Stack Overflow community has specifically decided to exclude the types of questions those communities are built around.  It is a choice between not having any SE site in which, for example, code reviews are on topic, or having a separate site from SO.  SO made the decision a while ago that code reviews didn't belong in the site's scope, given the design, rules, conventions, and participants in the site.  (Feel free to replace "code reviews" with the topics of each of those other sites.)

Each of these sub-site have made a point of creating entirely separate conventions, rules, and guidelines for how the site should be used.  The differing guidelines are specifically targeted towards the radically different style of questions being asked.

Comment: Pretty much what I was going to say.  Using the tag system to differentiate the different site topic *wouldn't get the job done,* because the Help Center (and the tag structure) is different for each site and scope.

Comment: Thanks for answer, makes sense now!

Answer (score 3):

There's already tons of questions being asked daily on SO. If we add to this total the code review questions and the questions that are being asked on SO, we'll get a humongous amount of questions. We can't answer all questions as things are right now, I don't think adding more acceptable subjects will improve the rate of answered questions.

Moreover, SE is trying to create site that target specific subjects; music, skeptics, personal finance, the workplace, etc.. Programming is quite large, and contains many sub-parts that can be considered as a whole subject by themselves. Coding problems (currently answered on SO) is one of them. Programming techniques is a totally different one (Programmers.SE), and deserve it's own website, with its own set of experts. Same applies, IMO, to coding review.

If we apply the logic you bring forth in your question, we should also question the existence of the many websites created for specific technologies (Drupal, TeX/LaTeX, etc.).